# How to determine the DNS Zone from the output of dig?

Tags: domain-name-system

Its a basic question question (a lil confused), does the authority section specify the DNS zone ?

```
dig -x 74.125.225.33
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> -x 74.125.225.33
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;;->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63716
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;33.225.125.74.in-addr.arpa.    IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
33.225.125.74.in-addr.arpa. 51707 IN    PTR ord08s06-in-f1.1e100.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
125.74.in-addr.arpa.    56447   IN  NS  NS3.GOOGLE.COM.
125.74.in-addr.arpa.    56447   IN  NS  NS2.GOOGLE.COM.
125.74.in-addr.arpa.    56447   IN  NS  NS4.GOOGLE.COM.
125.74.in-addr.arpa.    56447   IN  NS  NS1.GOOGLE.COM.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
NS1.GOOGLE.COM.     213489  IN  A   216.239.32.10
NS2.GOOGLE.COM.     213489  IN  A   216.239.34.10
NS3.GOOGLE.COM.     213489  IN  A   216.239.36.10
NS4.GOOGLE.COM.     213489  IN  A   216.239.38.10
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'determine the DNS zone'?

Comment: What exactly is a DNS zone ?

Answer (score 3):

> The authority section tells us what DNS servers can provide an
>   authoritative answer to our query.

In your example, google.com has 4 authoritative nameservers.   Authoritative nameservers are those configured to answer DNS queries directly for a specific domain as opposed to simply caching DNS lookups from other servers.

When you register a domain, you list your authoritative nameservers so that systems know which nameservers to trust.

See:
http://www.madboa.com/geek/dig/

Answer (score 2):

Fast answer is no.  `dig` will just tell who controls that address.

`whois` will give you the publicly available IP address allocation data.  However, the network block may have been split into smaller zones which are not publicly announce.